# Need of Return parameter in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

SP definition with Return Parameter

```
if OBJECT_ID('CountSeatleEmployee') is not null
drop proc CountSeatleEmployee

go

CREATE PROC CountSeatleEmployee
AS 
DECLARE @Total int
SELECT @Total =Count(*) 
from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person] P
WHERE P.EMAILPROMOTION =0
RETURN @Total

--Execute SP
declare @Count int
exec @Count = CountSeatleEmployee
SELECT @COUNT
--11158 Records

--same SP without Return Parameter

if OBJECT_ID('CountSeatleEmployee') is not null
drop proc CountSeatleEmployee
go
CREATE PROC CountSeatleEmployee
AS 
SELECT Count(*) 
from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person] P
WHERE P.EMAILPROMOTION =0

exec CountSeatleEmployee'
```

Now why not simply use below . These two are providing same output. Why do we seed return parameter

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, return values are usually used for error conditions.  Not everyone has the same experience.

The RETURN statement is limited to returning an integer so it's usefulness is somewhat limited (in my opinion).  I prefer the second method because it allows for more consistency in your code.  Imagine you wanted a name instead of a count, you would not be able to use the return statement.

On the other hand, some people prefer the first method that uses the return statement (wherever it is possible to do so).  The justification is that it is an optimization technique.  When you call the first code example from your front end, there is no need to process the procedure with the expectation that it would return a result set.  Instead, it's just a single 4 byte value passed back from the database.  The second example requires more processing on the front end because a procedure can return all sorts of things.  It could return multiple result sets and each result set could contain multiple columns and multiple rows.  Your front end code needs to evaluate the data coming back and then build the proper structure for handling the data.  This takes extra CPU cycles.

I'm not necessarily recommending one over the other, I'm just trying to explain the rationale.

Answer (score 0):

The one way provides the  information in a return variable which you then convert into a recordset with the Select of the variable, the other as a dataset or recordset. It depends on the application which one you want to use.

```
if OBJECT_ID('CountSeatleEmployee') is not null
drop proc CountSeatleEmployee

go

CREATE PROC CountSeatleEmployee
AS 
DECLARE @Total int
SELECT @Total =Count(*) 
from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person] P
WHERE P.EMAILPROMOTION =0


Select * from [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person] P
WHERE P.EMAILPROMOTION =0
RETURN @Total

--Execute SP
declare @Count int
exec @Count = CountSeatleEmployee   --This will return the recordset of the table and returns the total rows into the variable @Count
SELECT @COUNT
```